# How can I list all available LogRecord attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, metadata, python-logging

The official documentation provides a table with [all available attributes for logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes).

These attributes, in turn, can be used in formatters (e.g. `'[{asctime}] {levelname} [{threadName}] [{name}.{funcName}:{lineno}] {message}'` is one such formatter).

However, can I get a list of all available attributes during runtime, without relying on the documentation?

Let's say that my goal is to procedurally generate a formatter that includes all attributes independently of the version. As the documentation itself notes, `processName` was added in 3.1 and wasn't listed there when it was still 3.0, meaning that if my script used hard-coded 3.0 attributes it wouldn't use `processName` even if it was running in a 3.1^ interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instantiate a LogRecord and look at it. You probably want to filter the standard `__` attributes.

```
import logging

rec = logging.LogRecord('',0,None,0,'',[],None) # create a minimal LogRecord
all_attributes = dir(rec)
filtered_attributes = [a for a in all_attributes if '__' not in a]
```